# autofilter in sheet using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

i am using apache poi in which i set autofilter to all column .i also get data by filtering 1 column but when i want to filter 2 column and get data no any of them(filter) is applied on sheet.

```
outputSheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:F136"));
CTAutoFilter sheetFilter=outputSheet.getCTWorksheet().getAutoFilter();


CTFilterColumn  myFilterColumn=sheetFilter.insertNewFilterColumn(0);
myFilterColumn.setColId(1);

CTFilterColumn  myFilterColumn2=sheetFilter.insertNewFilterColumn(1);
myFilterColumn2.setColId(6);

CTFilters firstColumnFilter=myFilterColumn.addNewFilters();
CTFilter myFilter1=firstColumnFilter.addNewFilter();

CTFilters secondColumnFilter=myFilterColumn2.addNewFilters();
CTFilter myFilter2=secondColumnFilter.addNewFilter();


myFilter1.setVal("fidelity.com");
myFilter2.setVal("US");

List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("Ad Cloud");

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list2.add("US");

XSSFRow r1;

for(Row r : my_sheet) {
    for (Cell c : r) {

        c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        if ( (c.getColumnIndex()==1 && !list2.contains(c.getStringCellValue())) || (c.getColumnIndex()==6 && !list1.contains(c.getStringCellValue())) ){
            r1=(XSSFRow) c.getRow();

            if (r1.getRowNum()!=0) { /* Ignore top row */
                /* Hide Row that does not meet Filter Criteria */
                r1.getCTRow().setHidden(true); 
            }
        }
    }
}

outputworkbook.write(fos);
    fos.close();
    //format(outputFile);
}
```

Comment: `.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:F136"))` ... `myFilterColumn2.setColId(6)`: Column Id `6` is column `G` since column `A` is `0`. So you are setting a filter column outside the filter range. Also your code sets filter value `myFilter1.setVal("fidelity.com")` and value for hiding the row `list1.add("Ad Cloud")` different.

Comment: by changing column id and setval still not working